# How did Batman fake his death in The Dark Knight Returns?

Tags: dc, batman, dark-knight-returns-2012, dark-knight-returns

At the end of Frank Miller's The Dark Knight Returns, Batman beats up Superman and delivers the iconic quote:

> ***I want you to remember, Clark. In all the years to come, in your most private moments, I want you to remember, my hand, at your throat, I want you to remember, the one man who beat you***

Then Superman notices that Batman's heart was growing weaker and before he could say or do anything, Batman collapses and dies (apparently).

So, how exactly did he fake his death? Superman obviously could hear his heartbeat and he himself declared Batman dead.

Did Batman use some sort of serum to bring his heartbeat to a unbelievably low beat that even Superman couldn't detect?

Comment: This is answered in the comic and yes he did use a drug to stop his heart from beating. Later, at the funeral, Superman (as Clark Kent) hears Bruce's heartbeat, and leaves with a smile on his face. If I weren't at work I'd leave a more detailed answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

He took a drug to disguise his lifesigns (either that or a viagra).

[image]

It disguised his heartbeat *until his funeral*.

[image]